# Can my save data carry over from GFWL to the Xbox 360?

Tags: fallout-3, grand-theft-auto-iv, games-for-windows-live

If I played GTA IV/Fallout 3 on my PC with my Xbox Live account, can I buy GTA IV/Fallout 3 for the Xbox 360 and play on the same account, will I have my save data? (No mods)

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain.

Comment: Don't have solid proof, but generally cloud saves are not cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  GFWL offers very little in functionality between Windows and Xbox.  If you want to transfer your saves, you can try to use a USB drive and a save conversion program, but this is unreliable.  I previously tried to transfer a Skyrim save between Xbox and PC with limited results.  Your mileage may vary.